# Reading *special* XLS files into Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, xls

I have to write some VBA to import about 100 .XLS files.
I can do that easily, BUT these are not *real* XLS. I think they are generated by Cognos Impromptu (or whatever old tool). When I look at them with an editor, here is the header:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Document-Type: Workbook
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_01C3B8B1.6DB8B6D0"

This document is formatted for viewing in Microsoft Excel 2002 and subsequent versions. You are using a previous version of Excel.

------=_NextPart_01C3B8B1.6DB8B6D0
Content-Location: file:///C:/CE594991/xls.htm
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

<html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta name=3D"Excel Workbook Frameset">
<link rel=3DFile-List href=3D"xls_files/filelist.xml">
<meta http-equiv=3DContent-Type content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dwindows-12=
52">
<meta nam

e=3DGenerator content=3D"Microsoft Excel 9">
```

I cant't even link those manually in Access.
When I try to open them in Excel, Excel complains that they have the wrong extension, but then opens them perfectly.

Any clue on the technique for reading those from Access VBA ?
For the prototype I had "good" XLS files and I was using a query like this one to read them (super fast method):

```
SELECT sh.field1, sh.field2, sh.fiel5
FROM [List_Frame$] AS sh IN '' [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=\\myServer\someFolder\xxx_Fund_Details_20170906.xlsb];
```

Comment: Ask the supplier to pass you files similar to the prototype. What other purpose would a prototype have?

Comment: Can you not just open it in Excel and then save it in an updated format?

Comment: @Gustav :-) you never worked with banks, right ?

Comment: @braX yes I can probably do that, but you would love to avoid it, since it's a daily process with > 100 files to import, and I'd like it to be fast. Ideally I would imagine that if Excel can read it, there could be a magic connection string that I could use...

Comment: Yes. Then the formats of the sample files matched the format of the real files.

Comment: It looks like an excel file that was save/exported as HTML. You could create an instance of Excel in Access to convert them back to a standard `.xls` or `.xlsx`.

Comment: Alternate to saving them in excel format first: how about reading it as a text file and inserting it directly into your DB? I suspect that it would require a parser UDF but theoretically should be quicker than excel conversion

Comment: Have you tried with the `.htm` extension ? This htm format seems to works just fine with the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4` and `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` providers. Note that your example is an HTTP response. Therefore you need to extract the body to get the content of the excel file.

Comment: @FlorentB. Indeed, looking further down I have a <head> and <body> sections. I think it might be a "mht" format (saved web page). It seems to come from a quite old reporting tool.

Comment: @Zac Indeed, in terms of performance I could create a class module to read those, if no magic solution appears ;-) Should not be that complicated  since I can isolate the <body> section.

Comment: @FlorentB. is right. I can replicate this with a random .htm file. Named _mht_ it just opens; named _xls_, Excel complains about the extension, then opens it. Interesting.

Comment: @Patrick Honorez, from your example the excel file (response body) starts at `<html>` and should end at `</html>`. Be also aware that your example is a multi-part http response, which mean that the whole excel file may be split into multiple http responses.